# Is Homosexual act the only capitally punishable biological predisposition?

Tags: halacha, homosexuality

First, I assume homosexuality has some biological (genetic) background (*to say the least*).

Second, in the list of [Capital Sins](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1172738/jewish/Sanhedrin-vehaOnashin-haMesurin-lahem-Chapter-15.htm), I assume that murder (maybe psychopathic) or general adultery are not biologically predisposed. So are Shabbos transgressors or idolaters.

Does it leave homosexual acts as the only capital sin that is innately predisposed?

I would like to know if somebody discusses this distinction and explains it.

Comment: You can read the list as well as we can, I'd think. What are you asking us for?

Comment: @DoubleAA I added "I would like to know if somebody discusses this distinction and explains it."

Comment: Do you have a source for your first assumption? If not the whole question is irrelevant.

Comment: Your third sentence is phrased as a question but actually seems to be the predetermined conclusion of your assumptions. If you assume that homosexuality is biological, and you assume that all other sins towards which one has an inclination are not biological, then yes that pretty much by definition leaves homosexual acts as the only capital sin that is biologically predisposed.

Answer (score 5):

Absolutely not. Many other sexual unions are also capital sins, and people are biologically inclined toward them. Also, the consumption of *chametz* on Passover is a capital sin, and doubtless you've been biologically inclined toward it yourself: at any rate, I have.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72148/discussion-on-answer-by-msh210-is-homosexual-act-the-only-capitally-punishable-b).

Answer (score 1):

Why do you say adultery is not biologically predisposed?
This question seems to be rooted in a misunderstanding of aveiras in general. The reason that the Torah forbids certain acts is because we have desires to commit them. If a person has a homosexual desire, it is equivalent to an heterosexual desire for someone else's wife. Both actions are forbidden and punishable by death. There is nothing special about homosexuality here.

Comment: A basic difference between homosexual and heterosexual desires is that the latter has plenty of permissible manifestations while the former does not.